# How to use the to_char funtion with different formats based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to know how I can use the to_char query in SQL.

```
Name    Gender  Salary  Start_Date
------- ------- ------- ----------
Sally   Female  45000   23/02/2001
Frank   Male    23200   15/12/2008
```

The start_date is in the format DD/MM/YYYY, from my understanding the to_char function allows us to view dates in other formats. How do I use it to show MM/DD/YYYY for Frank only?

Comment: Bizarre requirement - do users really want the date column to show inconsistent date formats?

Comment: It was for my own training, just runing through all the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I use it to show MM/DD/YYYY for Frank only?

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT name,
       gender,
       salary,
       CASE name
         WHEN 'Frank'
         THEN TO_CHAR( start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
         ELSE TO_CHAR( start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
       END AS start_date
FROM   your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

try decode (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

```
with a(name,start_date) as (
           select 'Sally' , to_date('23/02/2001','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual 
             union all
           select 'Frank' , to_date('15/12/2008','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual )
select name,
       decode(name,'Frank',to_char(start_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'),to_char(start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')) start_date
  from a
```

output:

```
NAME  START_DATE
----- ----------
Sally 23/02/2001 
Frank 12/15/2008
```

Answer (score 0):

with select statement,

SELECT col-name1,col-name2, TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM table-name;

Comment: The OP said he wants one format for Frank only, and a different format for the other rows. This solution doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, tho this is good for when you want to view the whole table in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Decode**

```
SELECT name,
   gender,
   salary,
   Decode(name,'Frank',TO_CHAR( start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ),
          TO_CHAR( start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
   END AS start_date  FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Read others response before posting yours and if you find that your thoughts have already been expressed, no need to re-iterate the same.